# set positions for particles (particule systems) with python

Tags: python, animation, modifiers, particles

I'm learning to make 3D model in Blender with python scripts, and I have 3 questions for particle systems :

1) I have a cube with some dimension (lx,ly,lz) and I want to add (n) particles inside the cube with specific positions (x,y,z), can I do it with python script? If yes, what is the instruction the give the postions?

2)Can I see the 3D model of the pores inside the cube? I mean by that "see the difference boolean operation between the cube and the particles".

3) My third question is about animation : Can I launch an animaion if I have the evolution of positions of particles with time?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Best regards,

Walid